# Do $fopen and $fwrite works with FPGA implementation also?

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog, virtex-series-fpga

I used $fopen , $fclose and $ fwrite in my verilog code. It worked with simulation but when i did FPGA implementation it is not working. My question is that these works with FPGA implementation also or not?

Comment: What would you expect them to do on an FPGA? They need a filesystem of some form to have much meaning.

Comment: I want my output data (which I stored on BRAM after the code run) on text file.

Comment: What text file? Where?

Comment: You will need to put together done verilog code to push the bram contents out over some interface. If you have a chipscope license, then you could use a dual port RAM with a counter on one port and then just probe it with chipscope. Alternatively you could dump it out of a serial port.

Comment: You have to understand that there are 2 different types of Verilog, one is for simulation and verification, the other is for creating a netlist for the FPGA (synthesizable code), what you are trying to do is not synthesizable and therefore is not supported by an FPGA.

Answer (score 2):

SystemVerilog is a hardware description and verification language that has hooks into the host operating system that runs the simulation. None of these hooks are available to you in the actual hardware. However, if you are running your FPGA on a development board, then there may be hooks that the FPGA vendor provided to dump you memories to a file.

Answer (score 1):

No, obviously not - how could it? None of the `$` extensions do.

Answer (score 1):

Most synthesis tools don't support read/write support. Some of them report the usage of such functions as an error, others ignore such statement or even don't implement `Std.TextIO`.

Xilinx ISE supports read/write in VHDL (I have not tested Verilog).
Xilinx Vivado has some issues with file i/o.

Contrary common consensus, there a good usecases for file i/o at synthesis time:

1. reading content for ROMs
2. writing information for debugging purposes onto the disk
3. exporting of address and register mappings
4. ...

**Usecase 2:**
It's possible to export FSM encodings, enum-encodings and more to *.tok files, which can be read back by Xilinx ChipScope, to display complex signals like FSM-states as a name in the waveform.

**Usecase 3:**
It's possible to export the bus-address to device-register mapping of a SoC design as a list of constant-definitions in assembly language. This file can be included into the assembly project. So if the designer maps a SoC device to another address range, the register mapping in the assembly is updated by the next synthesis run.

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about doing file I/O *during synthesis*. He wants to have the actual FPGA reading and writing files while it is running.

Comment: Hmmm, indeed the question is a bit unclear in that point.

Comment: The question is quite clear - the OP wants to write out the contents of RAM after execution, presumably to see if _"it worked"_